# Add event listener that changes / removes class when sound is done playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

How would I add an event listener that performs a function to remove class when a sound file has ended. (Make the Play button in Jsfiddle turn back to green when done playing)

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wyfjdgyb/4/

```
$(".play").on('click',function(){
    var key = $(this).attr('key');     
    EvalSound(key);
    var this_play = $(this);
    $(".play").each(function() {
        if ($(this)[0] != this_play[0]) {
            $(this).removeClass("pause");
        }
    });
    $( this ).toggleClass( "pause" );
});

var thissound = new Audio();
var currentKey;
function EvalSound(key) {
    if(currentKey !== key)
        thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/beats/" + key + ".mp3";      
    currentKey = key;

    if (thissound.paused)
        thissound.play();
    else
        thissound.pause();
        thissound.currentTime = 0;
        currentPlayer = thissound;     
}
$(".play").bind('ended', function(){
    // done playing
    $(this).removeClass("pause");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with the help of `current Time` and `duration` properties of the `audio` object. You should set an interval(with the help of [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function) with a low delay to check if those 2 properties are identical. When they will become identical it will mean that the audio track reached its end. Keep in mind to clear intervals when you will need to.

```
var interval;
function EvalSound(key) {

    if(currentKey !== key)
        thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/beats/" + key + ".mp3";      
    currentKey = key;

    if (thissound.paused) {
        thissound.play();
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(thissound.currentTime == thissound.duration) {
                clearInterval(interval);    
                console.log('Sound played!');
            }           
        },100);
    } else {
        thissound.pause();
        thissound.currentTime = 0;
        currentPlayer = thissound;
        clearInterval(interval);   
    }    
}
```

Here is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyfjdgyb/6/).

PS: Nice beats, dude! :)

Comment: Works Great! Thanks Lazarev!

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the ended handler to the sound element not to the DOM element and pass the clicked element to your function.

Code:

```
 function EvalSound(el, key) {

     thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
         // done playing
         $(el).removeClass("pause");
     });

     if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/beats/" + key + ".mp3";
     currentKey = key;

     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();
     thissound.currentTime = 0;
     currentPlayer = thissound;

 }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9a9jbqzz/